# python how to transfer data like u'**\t**\r**\t**\r' to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have some data like this,

`u'1\t\u80a1\u7968\r2\t\u503a\u5238\r3\tTOT-\u6211\u53f8\u5355\u4e2a\u4fe1\u6258\u8ba1\u5212\uff08\u7a7f\u900f\u5f0f\uff09\r4\tTOT-\u6211\u53f8\u591a\u4e2a\u4fe1\u6258\u8ba1\u5212\r5\tTOT-\u5916\u90e8\u4fe1\u6258\u8ba1\u5212\r6\tFOF-\u6307\u5b9a\u5355\u4e2a\u5916\u90e8\u4ea7\u54c1\r7\tFOF-\u6307\u5b9a\u591a\u4e2a\u5916\u90e8\u4ea7\u54c1\r8\t\u80a1\u7968\u5b9a\u589e\r9\t\u80a1\u7968\u8d28\u62bc\r10\t\u79c1\u52df\u57fa\u91d1\uff08\u6211\u53f8\uff09\r99\t\u5176\u4ed6\r'.`

I want transfer those to pandas dataframe. So,what should I do?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: pandas.read_csv(filename, sep='\t') tab separated?

Comment: I read those data from access db，so read_csv() can't work. I want to output  like this:
'''
index    name
1 股票
2 债券
3 TOT-我司单个信托计划（穿透式）
4 TOT-我司多个信托计划
5 TOT-外部信托计划
6 FOF-指定单个外部产品
7 FOF-指定多个外部产品
8 股票定增
9 股票质押
10 私募基金（我司）
99 其他
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert you `string` to a `dict` and use that to create a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = u'1\t\u80a1\u7968\r2\t\u503a\u5238\r3\tTOT-\u6211\u53f8\u5355\u4e2a\u4fe1\u6258\u8ba1\u5212\uff08\u7a7f\u900f\u5f0f\uff09\r4\tTOT-\u6211\u53f8\u591a\u4e2a\u4fe1\u6258\u8ba1\u5212\r5\tTOT-\u5916\u90e8\u4fe1\u6258\u8ba1\u5212\r6\tFOF-\u6307\u5b9a\u5355\u4e2a\u5916\u90e8\u4ea7\u54c1\r7\tFOF-\u6307\u5b9a\u591a\u4e2a\u5916\u90e8\u4ea7\u54c1\r8\t\u80a1\u7968\u5b9a\u589e\r9\t\u80a1\u7968\u8d28\u62bc\r10\t\u79c1\u52df\u57fa\u91d1\uff08\u6211\u53f8\uff09\r99\t\u5176\u4ed6\r'

>>> dct = dict(line.split('\t') for line in s.strip().split('\r'))
>>> print(dct)
{'1': '股票', '2': '债券', '3': 'TOT-我司单个信托计划（穿透式）', '4': 'TOT-我司多个信托计划', '5': 'TOT-外部信托计划', '6': 'FOF-指定单个外部产品', '7': 'FOF-指定多个外部产品', '8': '股票定增', '9': '股票质押', '10': '私募基金（我司）', '99': '其他'}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index')
>>> print(df)
                    0
1                  股票
2                  债券
3   TOT-我司单个信托计划（穿透式）
4        TOT-我司多个信托计划
5          TOT-外部信托计划
6        FOF-指定单个外部产品
7        FOF-指定多个外部产品
8                股票定增
9                股票质押
10           私募基金（我司）
99                 其他
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an Idea how to achieve your goal, here I only took a part of your string and converted, If you want to apply this to your data you have to make some changes , Because data is not in correct format.

```
print('\\u80a1\\u7968'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

It will o/p like :

```
股票
```